# How to fix typeerror: 'list' object not callable error in bubble sorting a list while working in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to sort a list using bubble sort and had written this code, but an error showing typeerror:'list' object not callable came. Where did I make a mistake?

I have tried to enter my list elements in different ways, ie, including decimal numbers etc. but still doesn't work.

```
def swap(a,b):
    if a > b:
        t = a
        a = b
        b = t
        return a,b
def sort(list):
    k=0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)):
            if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                (a,b) = swap(list[j],list(j+1))
                list[j] = a
                list[j+1] = b
                k+=1    
                print(k,'  ',list)
            else:
                k+=1
                continue

    print(list)

list = [5,6,89,2,1,42,23,46,0,83]
sort(list)
```

I expect the list as [0,1,2,5,6,23,42,83,89]

Comment: `list(j+1)` -> `list[j+1]` please could you just take a closer look at your code before posting a question next time? Also, please don't name your variables "list", "dict', etc..., it is visual diarrhea in terms of bad coding practices.

Comment: You dont need all that stuff, lists already support such kind of sorting: `lst=[5,6,89,2,1,42,23,46,0,83]; lst.sort(); print(lst)`

Comment: @grapes If the OP is tempted to use bubble sort, he is not trying to obtain a sorted list; he is trying to learn to write code.  Using `list.sort` doesn't help with that.

Comment: @MartinBonner, you are right

Comment: Hi all, actually I am new to Python and so am making several mistakes as bro coldspeed has pointed out. I will definitely try to correct myself next time before posting. And @MartinBonner, you are right. I was trying to learn bubble sort.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed I corrected list(j+1) to list[j+1] and the typeerror was gone. Really thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. The error `'list' object not callable` occurs when you use `()` instead of `[]`. To fix it, replace `(a,b) = swap(list[j],list(j+1))` with  `(a,b) = swap(list[j],list[j+1])`
2. The following code is giving your required result. Sorry, for bad indentation and thanks @delirium and @iBug:

Function:

```
   def swap(a,b):
       if a > b:
           t = a
           a = b
           b = t
       return a,b
   def sort(list):
       k=0
       for i in range(len(list)):
           for j in range(len(list)-1): #Change Here
               if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                   (a,b) = swap(list[j],list[j+1]) #Change here
                   list[j] = a
                   list[j+1] = b
                   k+=1
                   #print(k,'  ',list)  #Change here
               else:
                   k+=1
                   continue

        print(list)

    list = [5,6,89,2,1,42,23,46,0,83]
    sort(list)
```

Comment: Thanks, @delirium

Comment: the whole `else` part can be dropped

Answer (score 3):

`list(j+1)` is wrong. 'list' object is not callable. Also in bubble sort, the second loop is till second last element in the list `ie. range(len(list)-1)`

```
def swap(a,b):
    if a > b:
        t = a
        a = b
        b = t
        return a,b
def sort(list):
    k=0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)-1): #Change Here
            if list[j] > list[j+1]:
                (a,b) = swap(list[j],list[j+1]) #Change here
                list[j] = a
                list[j+1] = b
                k+=1
                print(k,'  ',list)
            else:
                k+=1
                continue

    print(list)

list = [5,6,89,2,1,42,23,46,0,83]
sort(list)
```

Output

```
3    [5, 6, 2, 89, 1, 42, 23, 46, 0, 83]
4    [5, 6, 2, 1, 89, 42, 23, 46, 0, 83]
5    [5, 6, 2, 1, 42, 89, 23, 46, 0, 83]
6    [5, 6, 2, 1, 42, 23, 89, 46, 0, 83]
7    [5, 6, 2, 1, 42, 23, 46, 89, 0, 83]
8    [5, 6, 2, 1, 42, 23, 46, 0, 89, 83]
9    [5, 6, 2, 1, 42, 23, 46, 0, 83, 89]
11    [5, 2, 6, 1, 42, 23, 46, 0, 83, 89]
12    [5, 2, 1, 6, 42, 23, 46, 0, 83, 89]
14    [5, 2, 1, 6, 23, 42, 46, 0, 83, 89]
16    [5, 2, 1, 6, 23, 42, 0, 46, 83, 89]
19    [2, 5, 1, 6, 23, 42, 0, 46, 83, 89]
20    [2, 1, 5, 6, 23, 42, 0, 46, 83, 89]
24    [2, 1, 5, 6, 23, 0, 42, 46, 83, 89]
28    [1, 2, 5, 6, 23, 0, 42, 46, 83, 89]
32    [1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
40    [1, 2, 5, 0, 6, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
48    [1, 2, 0, 5, 6, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
56    [1, 0, 2, 5, 6, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
64    [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 23, 42, 46, 83, 89]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
swap(list[j],list(j+1))
```

Should be

```
swap(list[j],list[j+1])
```

At least that's where the syntax is wrong, didn't check your algorithm